# How to Keep Same UINavigationView Button across all storyboard views?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, xcode4.2, storyboard

So I'm working through the code in [this tutorial](http://blog.whitepeaksoftware.com/2010/09/11/customizing-the-look-of-uinavigationbar-and-uinavigationcontroller/) which has a small button labeled 'Touch Me'. When you tap this it brings up a new view which also has a close button. I've added a screenshot below and you can [download the source code here](http://api.cld.me/DKl7/download/AnotherUITabViewSource.zip).

[image: app ui top bar]

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to port over this .xib code to work in Xcode 4.2 storyboards. I am trying to keep that same 'Touch' button and 'AnotherView' displaying on a brand new 'Master-Detail Application' running iOS 5.

I am struggling to even keep the button displaying on every view. As in, you can tap the button 'Touch Me' to bring up this alternate view at any page - in the table view or the detail view. I hope this makes some sense? Note that I'm NOT talking about the table row, just the top right button in the UINavigationBar.

Please let me know if I can provide any more details! Just trying to build a similar functionality as the 'Touch Me' button in a fresh new iOS 5/Xcode 4.2 Storyboard app WITHOUT any .xib files. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your know storyboard doesn't use XIBs so you won't be able to follow the tutorial line for line.

I recommended first creating a new storyboard project and select the "Master-Detail Application" template when creating the project. This will create a project with a Navigation controller. You can then follow the tutorial on customizing the navigation bar. When following the first part of the tutorial, you will need to select the initial view,"Navigation Controller", in storyboard and change its class to "KTNavigationBar" after you create that class.

Comment: well see the thing is I'm not really trying to follow the tutorial for iOS5. I just want to duplicate the button functionality where you push it and it slides up a new view - I can see how they coded this in iOS4 with .xib files but I can't port the code over to the new Xcode storyboards.

Comment: In that case you don't need a navigation controller. Just add two view controllers to your storyboard. Place a button in your first view. Controller-click drag from that button to the second view creating a segue. Select the segue modal with the menu that pops up. Then select the segue and use the attribute inspector to change the transition type to cover vertical. When you want to return from the second view controller to the first use the statement [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES].

Comment: awesome dude thank you this helped a lot. I'll post up a new thread if I have problems, but I follow all your methods!